# Why would a sane person use Jordan form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

What is the advantage of using the [Jordan form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) to solve linear differential equations?

Isn't it much faster to use the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) for high order equations?

And in the case of a linear system we could convert it into a single equation.

Comment: The gist is that for big systems of linear equations, it is significantly faster to use Jordan Normal form.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Bigger than 4x4?

Comment: Even for $4 \times 4$ it's a toss-up.  For $5 \times 5$ and bigger, you start to run into problems with factoring the associated polynomial because there's nothing like the "quadratic formula" for polynomials [of degree 5 and higher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok, but to know the eigenvalues you would also have to factor de polynomial.

Comment: Actually, for computation, Jordan Normal form tends to be a pain because it's very sensitive to small changes.  I think that algorithms for solving this stuff with a computer use something like the upper-triangular form of the matrix.

Comment: Eigenvalues of big matrices are generally found using the [QR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) rather than by solving the associated characteristic polynomial.  In fact, polynomials are often solved by finding an associated matrix and computing the eigenvalues in this manner.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We didn't do this in a numerical methods class (has to use couple of pages calculating subespaces and determinants), so that might be the reason why in many ODEs books the Jordan form is not explained in depth.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  I think Jordan Canonical form should be appreciated in its own right, though; it's a very useful algebraic tool, and a good way to grasp the situation.  With differential equations, having the intuitive notion of how solutions behave with respect to "eigenvectors" and "generalized eigenvectors" can be very helpful.

Comment: @jinawee: you don't need to factor or even find the polynomial to find the eigenvalues. You can find individual eigenvalues by other means and then factor them out (or break down the matrix piece-by-piece ). When matrices grow big, the computations to even find the characteristic polynomial sometimes become so tedious you would rather avoid it. Matrices with a side of many million are common in many applications nowadays.